# Get content of string before '+' character in python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

INPUT:

```
s = 'Coated tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Film-coated tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Modified-release tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Prolonged-release tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE'
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
s = 'Coated tablet, Film-coated tablet, Modified-release tablet, Prolonged-release tablet'
```

For each string like this, how do I get the necessary output in Python so that all elements after the + doesn't come.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What's not working? I tried solving this myself and it's do-able ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do split on `,` and then on `+` and fetch item at index `0`

```
', '.join([i.split("+")[0].strip() for i in s.split(",")])
```

Output

```
'Coated tablet, Film-coated tablet, Modified-release tablet, Prolonged-release tablet'
```

Comment: same solution as mine except my code looks horrible! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions,

It removes from `+` until it runs out of characters that aren't a comma

```
import re
s = 'Coated tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Film-coated tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Modified-release tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Prolonged-release tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE'

re.sub(" [+] [^,]+","",s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression:

```
import re

old_s = 'Coated tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Film-coated tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Modified-release tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE, Prolonged-release tablet + ALFUZOSIN HYDROCHLORIDE'
new_s = re.sub(r'\s\+.*?, | \+.*?$', ',', s)[:-1]

print(new_s)
>>> 'Coated tablet, Film-coated tablet, Modified-release tablet, Prolonged-release tablet'
```

On the left hand of the pipe `\s` indicates white space, `\+.*?,` looks for everything between a `+` and a `,`, on the right side, you're going for the end case where there is no comma, using `$` instead.

`[:-1]` because all matches are replaced by a comma, however, you don't want the comma at the end of your string.